# Combining multiple OpenAPI Specifications, that do not reference each other, during maven generate sources step

Tags: maven, swagger, openapi

A Backend Java Project has rest endpoints that are defined in multiple different locations, each with their own generated openapi-yaml.

In order to use this project together with an api gateway, I need to combine these yamls into 1, before stuffing the file into my war file.

These specifications are generated in the generate-sources phase. I have tried using the swagger-codege-maven-plugin, but this plugin only seems to combine references. My specs do not reference each other, they just define different endpoints.

Is there a way to combine the specs during compilation with maven? Does anyone know of a plugin that does this?

Essentially, I need to put all the components from 1 file into the component section of another file and all the paths of 1 file into the paths of another file

I appreciate the help and thank you for your time!

Comment: You know about openapi-generator-maven-plugin? Maybe I misunderstand your question?

Comment: The openapi-generator doesn't have the option to just combine openapi yamls
It can only combine yamls that use $ref to refernce each other, but $ref is very limited and doesnt have the option to bulk import paths or components

Comment: At the very least if it does, I could not find it in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

After searching around further I have found this small plugin

https://github.com/randomnoun/swagger-combine-maven-plugin

which after playing around with the settings for a bit, I have achieved the functionality I needed in my original post.